# Overlay with columns and verbatim environments

Tags: beamer, verbatim, columns, overlays

I want to show my text using the overlay function of Beamer.

[image: Example]

Following this sequence:

- Intro phrase 0 --> Item 1 --> Item 2 --> Code 4 and so on

Moreover, I would like to know how to align vertically the text content on the left column with the code on the right column (for example Code 3 in between Item 1 and Item 2, code 6 aligned with Item 5 ...). Up to now, I am using only spaces of the Verbatim environment.

In order to work with overlay and verbatim environment, it should be used the `onlyenv` environment. While the overlay in the columns environment is set with `<1->` etc.

Nonetheless, I am not able to show as I want my content.

Note: Once displayed I want the item/code to be shown for the rest of the slide, not on the contrary, to disappear.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme[titleformat=regular, numbering=fraction,
progressbar=frametitle, sectionpage=none]{metropolis}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}

% ----

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Overlay Example}
\vspace{0.8em}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{0.70\textwidth}
Intro phrase 0
\begin{enumerate}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2 \medskip
\end{enumerate}

Intro phrase 4
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 5
\item Item 7
\item Item 9
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\vrule{}
\begin{column}[t]{0.30\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]
  Code 3


\end{Verbatim}
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]


  Code 6


  Code 8    


  Code 10

\end{Verbatim}
\end{column}
\end{columns}   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you divide your questions into separate ones for the alignment and the uncovering?

Comment: Yes I can, but the main issue is related to the overlay. As I wrote, I can workaround the vertical alignment by using extra spaces in the Verbatim environment.

Answer (score 3):

This answer addresses only the alignment issues, not the overlay.

It uses the `verbatimbox` package to put the code content in LaTeX boxes.  Then I introduce the macro `\setverbbox[<extra -rule-depth>]` to set the most recently created `verbbox` on the right-hand side of the item.

The format for the item input will be

```
\item <Item text>
\begin{verbbox}[\footnotesize]
<Code>
\end{verbbox}
\setverbbox[<extra-rule-depth>]
```

This format assumes the item text is one line, less than the width up to the rule.  If not, one could place the item text into a top-aligned`\parbox`, as shown in the MWE for item 1.

```
\documentclass[11pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usetheme[titleformat=regular, numbering=fraction,
progressbar=frametitle, sectionpage=none]{metropolis}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,stackengine}
% ----
\newcommand\codewidth{3cm}
\newcommand\setverbbox[1][12pt]{\hfill\belowbaseline[-.7\ht\strutbox]{%
  \smash{\rule[-#1]{1pt}{\dimexpr#1+\ht\savedverbbox+3pt}}%
  \dp\savedverbbox=10pt\relax%
  \makebox[\codewidth][l]{\theverbbox}}\qquad\mbox{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Overlay Example}
Intro Phrase 0
\setverbbox[25pt]\\
\begin{enumerate}
\item \parbox[t]{5cm}{Item 1 is a bit longer than a single line\strut}
\begin{verbbox}[\footnotesize]
Code 3
\end{verbbox}
\setverbbox[18ex]

\item Item 2 
\end{enumerate}

Intro phrase 4\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 5
\begin{verbbox}[\footnotesize]
Code 6
Code 6 cont.
line 3 of code 6
\end{verbbox}
\setverbbox

\item Item 7
\begin{verbbox}[\footnotesize]
Code 8
\end{verbbox}
\setverbbox
\item Item 9
\begin{verbbox}[\footnotesize]
Code 10
2nd line code 10
\end{verbbox}
\setverbbox
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]